# OpenGL: combined Translate/Rotate/Scale matrix or keep them separate?

Tags: opengl, model, matrix

At my opengl application, I've got a GameObject class to describe models
and each model has one matrix to describe its translation / rotation / scale
and whenever I want to translate / rotate / scale, I simply call
something like, Model_Matrix->translate(dx, dy, dz) which operate directly on the model matrix
thus changing it permenantly.
so first I wanna know, is that the right way to do it? because many articles online
talk about three matrices, translation, rotation and scale which then are multiplied together to create the transformation matrix. and I use only one for
all calculations.

can anyone shed some light on this subject cause as it is now, i am confused

note: i do know some matrix math, just alittle though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend maintaining the transform as a Matrix (per object) because - if you keep them separately, you're introducing implicit knowledge about the order in which these operations are performed (and hence might produce different results).

One way to prevent the implicit ordering of the transforms from biting you is to use a class say - TransformGroup that can contain any number of TranslateTransform, RotateTransform and ScaleTransform, each of which allow you to modify and examine individual properties. To see an example of this method - look [here](https://github.com/ananthonline/graffiti/blob/master/Graffiti.Core/Math/TransformGroup.cs).

Comment: Animations usually performs operation a single transformation: this could be a reason to keep them separated.

Comment: What I tend to do is to use keyframes and even if they are described separately there (the "editor" bit of my solution above), my code returns matrices to me.

Comment: maybe I can use one Matrix for the whole transformation and then 3 matrices for translation / rotation / scale so I can keep track of my object easly, so when I rotate the object, I will need to rotate the main matrix and then the rotation matrix aswell

Comment: See my edits above that expand on what you mentioned above and also point to a sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just need the matrix itself, there is nothing wrong with simply maintaining one matrix. This might get tricky though in case you want to do things like camera transitions.

Imagine you have a matrix A (before) and a matrix B (after) and want your program to be able to move the camera (or object) continuously from the A perspective to the B perspective. This is hard (in particular, not uniquely determined by pure matrix algebra) if all you have is a matrix to determine each position.

However, if you do maintain scaling, rotation and translation separately, it might be suitable to do this not using matrices at all, but by maintaining `eye`, `center` and `up` vectors in accordance with the [gluLookAt](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) function.

Answer (score 0):

One disatvantage of having only one matrix is that the operations influence each other. i.E. if you do a scale(2,2,2), and than a translate(2,2,2), your model will move by *4* in everey axis, not by two as you might expect.
Same problem with rotations, but worse to understand ;)

Next problem is that scale() and rotate() always use the origin, which means that if you want to rotate or scale, you have to think about where your current translation is, and calculate with this values. Which is hard to do.

To find a strategy of how to scale/translate/rotate you have to think about what you want to do at wich phase of your objects lifes. Construction vs. later movement.

However, you can implement "better" matrix-operations, by sticking together the existing ones.
i.E pseudocode

```
scale(float[3] s, float[3] originPoint)
```

would be implemented as

```
translate(-originPoint); scale(s); translate(originPoint);
```

and

```
rotate(float alpha, float[3] p1, float[3] p2)
```

would be implemented as

```
translate(-p1); rotate(alpha, p2-p1); translate(p1);
```

And, not using scale() at all makes life easier.

Cheers, Frank